# Passing a condition parameter to a Method using Action

Tags: c#, delegates

I am using the MVVM pattern in a Silverlight 4.0 project. This project is getting data from a WCF service.

Here is an example of getting a collection of shipping methods:

**Interface:**

```
void GetShippingMethods(Action<ObservableCollection<ShipVia>, Exception> completed);
```

**ServiceAgent:**

```
 public void GetShippingMethods(Action<ObservableCollection<ShipVia>, Exception> completed)
    {
      InvoiceServiceClient client = new InvoiceServiceClient();
      client.GetShippingMethodsCompleted += (s, ea) =>
      {
        if (ea.Error != null)
        {
          completed(null, ea.Error);
        }
        else
        {
          completed(ea.Result, null);
        }
      };

      client.GetShippingMethodsAsync();

      client.CloseAsync();

}
```

ea.Result will get a list of the shipping methods from by service.

My Problem is when I want to get a list of invoice items, I need to pass in an InvoiceID so the returned Result will only give me a collection of invoice items for a specific invoice.

Is there any way to pass in an input parameter that can be passed to my WCF service?

UPDATE:
As it turns out, it was pretty simple:
All I needed to do to add a condition parameter is this

```
void GetShippingMethods(Action<ObservableCollection<ShipVia>, Exception> completed, int MethodID);
```

Comment: appreciate you posting the answer..